# Why my Wiremock is Not Starting in my Test

Tags: scala, wiremock

I have trait of wiremock like this:

```
trait WiremockSetup extends BeforeAndAfterAll { self: Suite =>

  import WireMockConfiguration._

  protected val wiremockServer = new WireMockServer(options().dynamicPort())

  override protected def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    super.beforeAll()
    wiremockServer.start()
  }

  override protected def afterAll(): Unit = {
    wiremockServer.stop()
    super.afterAll()
  }

}
```

And I mix the trait in my test class like this

```
class Foo extends FlatSpec with WiremockSetup{

"Test scneario" should "do something" in {
assert (1 == 1)
}

}
```

But I am seeing compilation problems like this:

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort. 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty9.JettyHttpServerFactory.buildHttpServer(JettyHttpServerFactory.java:63)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.<init>(WireMockServer.java:76)
```

Why is problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have this dependency:

```
"com.github.tomakehurst"  %  "wiremock-jre8"            % "2.22.0"
```

Comment: have that dependencies , evethough getting null pointer exception while running the test case.   this is the error i am getting "            java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.isRunning()"